# Как выбрать строку с самой ранней датой и самой поздней датой? C#

Tags: c#, datetime

У меня есть n-ое количество строк со столбцами дата, время, проход(1 или 0), мне нужно выделить цветом первую и последнюю строку, как это сделать?
Даты так же могут совпадать, поэтому вторым условием будет время

```
DateTime date = (DateTime)_date; // ссылается на столбец дата в таблице
var time = _time;  // ссылается на столбец время в таблице
var exit = _exit;  // ссылается на столбец проход в таблице
if (exit = 1 || ? || ? )
{
   // ???
}
```

Comment: так просто создайте анонимный объект для каждой строки, например, new { Date = _date + _time, Exit = _exit, Row = row } и сохраните их в список. Потом просто отсортируйте список по дате через Linq Sort и возьмите у нужного объекта его Row

Comment: у меня строки изначально стоят с сортировкой по дате и по времени, мне нужно просто взять когда человек прошёл через кпп первый раз и когда последний раз в свою смену и закрасить эти строки цветом, парадокс в том что строк может быть разное кол-во т.к. например в обед люди могут пройти через кпп несколько раз

Answer (score 0):

Вам по моему мнению понадобиться массив вот код:

```
    int ExecuteCount = 0; //Количество записей за весь объём(Количество проходов(как я думаю))
    int CountMassive = 10; // Количество записей
    string[] Date = new string[CountMassive]; // Массив
    void main()
{
    // Тут ваш код 
    WriteData(); // Вызов-Исполнение Функции
    // Вывод из массива
    console.WriteLine(Date[0])// первое число
    console.WriteLine(Date[CountMassive]) // последние
}
    void WriteData()// запись даты
{
    Date[i] = time;
    ExecuteCount++;
}
```

Comment: а используя запрос можно это как-то осуществить? мне кажется так проще будет, если например используя функции min/max взять поля даты и времени

Comment: Запрос tpc? 
Вам нужно поля времени и даты совместить и сделать первую и последнею?

Comment: sql запрос,
мне нужно из всех существующих полей выбрать первое поле(когда сотрудник пришёл) и последнее поле(когда он ушёл уже совсем)
я могу как-то в переменную записать sql запрос? например: переменная А это поле по запросу с самой ранней датой и самым раннем временем? а потом просто задать условие, если строка = А, то закрасить ее зеленым цветом

Comment: var Date = SqlClient.Main.CreateCommand("select * FROM ZTAE WHERE DATE_IN = (SELECT MIN(DATE_IN) FROM ZTAE) AND TIME_IN = (SELECT MIN(TIME_IN) FROM ZTAE) AND PR_EXIT = 0");

переменная будет так смотреть на этот запрос? чтобы я потом мог задать условие типа если строка  = Date то закрасить ее?